# EC2 user-data not starting my application

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am using user-data of ec2 instance to power up my auto scale instances and run the application. I am running node js application.

But it is not working properly. I have debugged and checked the instance cloud monitor output. So it says

`pm2 command not found`

After reading and investigating a lot I have found that the path for the command as root is not there.

As EC2 user-data when it tries to run it finds the path
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

After `ssh` as ec2-user it is

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin`

After `ssh` as `sudo su` it is

`/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

It works only for the last path.

So what is the way or script to run the command as root during launch of the instance provided by user-data?

Answer (score 1):

All thought to start your application with userdata is not recommended, because as per AWS documentation they are not assuring that instance will only come up after successful execution of user data. Even if user data failed it will spin up your instance.

For your problem, I assume if you give the complete absolute path of the binary, It will work.

> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/pm2

Better solution for this approach, create a service file for your application startup and start application with systemd or service.

Comment: I am being encountered to this problem when I am trying to do it `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`